# Check if currentRoute starts with some text(something/something/*...) in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, angular-ng-if

I want to stop loader from loading from few screens and therefore I applied ngIf at routes where loader isn't needed. Here is the code for app.component.ts :

```
<router-outlet>
  <app-spinner></app-spinner>
  <ngx-ui-loader *ngIf="!(currentRoute =='/dashboard' || currentRoute == '/vehicle/edit/')"></ngx-ui-loader>
</router-outlet>
```

app.component.html

```
this.currentRoute = "";
        this.router.events.subscribe((event: Event) => {
            if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
                this.currentRoute = event.url;
            }
    });
```

I need to add * to vehicle/edit URL as there can be any vehicle ID while fetching the edit page like : `/vehicle/edit/49042/1422`, `/vehicle/edit/49023/1421` and so on.

How to allow currentRoute accept /vehicle/edit/* ?

Comment: Could you please rephrase you question? It seems like you have two separate problems, one that refers to disabling loader on particular routes and second referring to router itself with ability to accept "infinite nested route".

Comment: Hi @lemek, I know how to disbale loader for particuar routes, providing that route is static and not dynamic(for example, with ids), I am not sure how can router accept dynamic URLS or simple all URLS starting with /vehicle/edit/

Comment: @AnchalGupta Use indexOf  , var index = currentRoute .indexOf( "vehicle/edit" );

Comment: Not really related, but I would use `/vehicle/:id/edit` instead of `/vehicle/edit/:id`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I applied a hack to solve this :

```
currentDynamicRouteVehicleClient: string;
this.currentDynamicRouteVehicleClient = this.currentRoute.slice(0, 15);
if(this.currentDynamicRouteVehicleClient == '/vehicles/edit/') {
   this.dynamicRouteValue = true;
}
```

And then passing this dynamicRoute to app.component.html like this :

```
<router-outlet>
  <app-spinner></app-spinner>
  <ngx-ui-loader *ngIf="!dynamicRouteValue"></ngx-ui-loader>
</router-outlet>
```

Henceforth, all the URLS starting with /vehicles/edit/ will by bypassed.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so to answer your question about route that accepts dynamic URLS/all URLS starting with `/vehicle/edit/`.

The "dummy" approach if you know that your nesting got limit, is to declare multiple routes with params, more-less like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '/vehicle/edit/', component: VehicleListComponent },
  { path: '/vehicle/edit/:id', component: VehicleEditComponent },
  { path: '/vehicle/edit/:parent/:id', component: VehicleEditComponent },
  { path: '/vehicle/edit/:grandparent/:parent/:id', component: VehicleEditComponent },
];
```

This will work, because Angular routing stops at very first matching path, so the order of your route declaration is important!

However, if you're dealing with very long nesting capability, better approach is to use custom route matcher:

```
import { UrlSegment } from '@angular/router';

const nestedCategoryMatcher = (url: UrlSegment[]) => {
  // Check if this regex actually match your requirements
  const regexMatcher = /^(vehicle\/edit)([\/][0-9]+.+)/;

  if (!url.join('/').match(regexMatcher)) return null;

  return ({ consumed: url });
}

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '/vehicle/edit/', component: VehicleListComponent },
  { matcher: nestedCategoryMatcher, component: VehicleEditComponent },
];
```

And remember, that by using matcher, you will have to retrieve your "params" manually in your components by splitting URL into segments.

```
this.route.url
  .subscribe(segments => {
    const urlSegment: UrlSegment[] = (segments as UrlSegment[]);
    console.log(urlSegment);
  });
```